# Open paypal options based on specific link

Tags: php, magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When i click on Paypal Express Checkout it sends me to `paypal website where i get 2 options`

1)`Pay with my Paypal Account`

2)`Pay with a Debit or Credit Card or Bill me Later`

[image]

Now the problem is `I want to add 2 Options in my checkout`

1) `Pay with paypal`

2)`Pay with Credit or Debit Card`

When User clicks on `Pay with paypal` then `first Paypal options need to open`. Like this

[image]

And When `they clicks on 2nd Option` then `second option needs to be opened`. Like this

[image]

`Can Anyone tell me how can i achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the landing page at the moment you execute the SetExpressCheckout API method.

If you look at the API reference for the `LANDINGPAGE` field :

> Type of PayPal page to display. It is one of the following values:
>
> Billing – Non-PayPal account
>
> Login – PayPal account login

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

So you have to create 2 options in you checkout, the first option (Pay with paypal) executes SetExpressCheckout with `LANDINGPAGE=Login` and the second option has to call the same method but with `LANDINGPAGE=Billing`